# How to when device booting, auto execute program on raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3. I want to execute a program when it boots.

I am not root.

This did not work:

1. `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
2. Between `fi` and `exit 0` write `sudo /my program/src/execute program &`
3. Reboot

How do I run a program when the Raspberry Pi boots?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux) . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](http://elinux.org/RPi_Debian_Auto_Login). Which allowed me to login automatically and load the desktop (startX)

For Auto Login:

```
sudo nano /etc/inittab
```

Scroll down to:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
```

and change to: (comment it out)

```
#1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
```

Under that line add:

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

and Save.

Then edited `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

Then I use this line to start the desktop on the RPi automatically when it boots:

```
su -l pi -c startx
```

Where `pi` is the user, and `startx` is the command to run.